Blazor dependency injection service not registered
I created an ASP.NET Blazor project. There is a Client which is a Blazor WebAssembly application, and it has a BaseLibrary where I store the DTOs and Entities, and a ClientLibrary that I use to call the APIs.
In the ClientLibrary, there is an IGenericServiceInterface interface and a GenericServiceImplementation. The GenericServiceImplementation inherits the functions of the IGenericServiceInterface, specifically for API calls. I have registered all of this in the Client's program.cs file and the _imports.razor.
The allergies, medication, disease, ingredient is a entity.
for example medication entity
using BaseLibrary.EntitiesRelation;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace BaseLibrary.Entities
{
    [Index(nameof(Medication_Name), IsUnique = true)]

    public class Medication
    {
        [Key]
        public int Medication_Id { get; set; }
        public string? Medication_Name { get; set; }

        // Relation N:M
        public virtual ICollection<Patient_Medication> PatientMedications { get; set; } = new List<Patient_Medication>();
    }
}

IGenericServiceInterface
using BaseLibrary.Responses;

namespace ClientLibrary.Services.Contracts
{
    public interface IGenericServiceInterface<T>
    {
        Task<List<T>> GetAll(string baseUrl);
        Task<T> GetById(int id, string baseUrl);
        Task<GeneralResponse> Insert(T item, string baseUrl);
        Task<GeneralResponse> Update(T item, string baseUrl);
        Task<GeneralResponse> Delete(int id, string baseUrl);
    }
}

GenericServiceImplementation
using System.Net.Http.Json;
using BaseLibrary.Responses;
using ClientLibrary.Helpers;
using ClientLibrary.Services.Contracts;

namespace ClientLibrary.Services.Implementations
{
    public class GenericServiceImplementation<T>(GetHttpClient getHttpClient) : IGenericServiceInterface<T>
    {

        // Create
        public async Task<GeneralResponse> Insert(T item, string baseUrl)
        {
            var httpClient = await getHttpClient.GetPrivateHttpClient();
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync($"{baseUrl}/add", item);
            var result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<GeneralResponse>();
            return result!;
        }

        // Read All
        public async Task<List<T>> GetAll(string baseUrl)
        {
            var httpClient = await getHttpClient.GetPrivateHttpClient();
            var result = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<T>>($"{baseUrl}/all");
            return result!;
        }

        // Update
        public async Task<GeneralResponse> Update(T item, string baseUrl)
        {
            var httpClient = await getHttpClient.GetPrivateHttpClient();
            var response = await httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync($"{baseUrl}/update", item);
            var result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<GeneralResponse>();
            return result!;
        }

        // Delete
        public async Task<GeneralResponse> Delete(int id, string baseUrl)
        {
            var httpClient = await getHttpClient.GetPrivateHttpClient();
            var response = await httpClient.DeleteAsync($"{baseUrl}/delete/{id}");
            var result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<GeneralResponse>();
            return result!;
        }

        
        public async Task<T> GetById(int id, string baseUrl)
        {
            var httpClient = await getHttpClient.GetPrivateHttpClient();
            var result = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<T>($"{baseUrl}/single/{id}");
            return result!;
        }

    }
}

Program.CS
builder.Services.AddScoped<IGenericServiceInterface<Allergies>, GenericServiceImplementation<Allergies>>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IGenericServiceInterface<Diseases>, GenericServiceImplementation<Diseases>>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IGenericServiceInterface<Ingredient>, GenericServiceImplementation<Ingredient>>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IGenericServiceInterface<Medication>, GenericServiceImplementation<Medication>>();

Imports.razor
@inject IGenericServiceInterface<Allergies> allergyService 
@inject IGenericServiceInterface<Diseases> diseaseService
@inject IGenericServiceInterface<Ingredient> ingredientService
@inject IGenericServiceInterface<Medication> medicationService

When i run the app and click on the allergies page this issue is display
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot provide a value for property 'medicationService' on type 'Client.Pages.ContentPages.AdminFunctions.Allergies'. There is no registered service of type 'ClientLibrary.Services.Contracts.IGenericServiceInterface`1[Client.Pages.ContentPages.AdminFunctions.Medication]'.
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'medicationService' on type 'Client.Pages.ContentPages.AdminFunctions.Allergies'. There is no registered service of type 'ClientLibrary.Services.Contracts.IGenericServiceInterface`1[Client.Pages.ContentPages.AdminFunctions.Medication]'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<CreatePropertyInjector>g__Initialize|1(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IComponent component)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.InstantiateComponent(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type componentType, IComponentRenderMode callerSpecifiedRenderMode, Nullable`1 parentComponentId)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InstantiateChildComponentOnFrame(RenderTreeFrame[] frames, Int32 frameIndex, Int32 parentComponentId)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewComponentFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewSubtree(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 newFrameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForFramesWithSameSequence(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldFrameIndex, Int32 newFrameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForFramesWithSameSequence(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldFrameIndex, Int32 newFrameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForFramesWithSameSequence(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldFrameIndex, Int32 newFrameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForFramesWithSameSequence(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldFrameIndex, Int32 newFrameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.ComputeDiff(Renderer renderer, RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, Int32 componentId, ArrayRange`1 oldTree, ArrayRange`1 newTree)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment, Exception& renderFragmentException)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry renderQueueEntry)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()

As you can see, I have injected everything everywhere, but I don't understand where the problem is.

Is the client library in nuget or as a project dependency?

Project dependency. Thats a C# Class library

What's the Medication make up? Please provude a sampke which could reproduce the issue with us.

I updated the question, with medication entity, interface and the implementation

I see
...  IGenericServiceInterface`1[Client.Pages.ContentPages.AdminFunctions.Medication]

So you probably have both a Medication.cs (entity) and a Medication.Razor[.cs] (blazor page). The error comes from  injecting the wrong one.
The quick solution would look like:
@inject IGenericServiceInterface<BaseLibrary.Entities.Medication> medicationService

But it's not a bad idea to suffix your pages: MedicationPage.razor

I am not really understand what you mean. But look i updated the question.

I mean that you have a class Medication (entity) and a class Medication (blazor page). And the error comes from using the wrong one.

OMG, I wouldn’t have thought that this was the problem. thank you very much!
